# Is there a difference between filter(cond) and flatMap(x => cond? of(x) : EMPTY)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm trying to understand what the difference would be between these two observables. The only difference in code is this:

```js
/**
* Inside rxjs pipe
*/
if(typeof x === 'number' && x > 3) {
    return of(x);
} else {
    return EMPTY;
}
```

vs:

```js
.filter(typeof x === 'number' && x > 3)
```

The test I'm running:

```js
const a$ = from([1, 6, '4']).pipe(
            tap(console.log),
            flatMap((x) => {
                if (typeof x === 'number') {
                    if (x > 3) {
                        return of(x);
                    }
                    return EMPTY;
                }
                return EMPTY;
            }),
            tap(console.log)
        );
        const sub_a = a$.subscribe(
            (x) => { console.log(x, 'success'); done(); },
            (e) => { console.log(e, 'error'); done(); },
            () => { console.log('complete'); sub_a.unsubscribe(); done(); }
        );
```

and:

```js
        const b$ = from([2, 5, '8']).pipe(
            tap(console.log),
            filter(x => typeof x === 'number' && x > 3),
            tap(console.log)
        );
        const sub_b = b$.subscribe(
            (x) => { console.log(x, 'success'); done(); },
            (e) => { console.log(e, 'error'); done(); },
            () => { console.log('complete'); sub_b.unsubscribe(); done(); }
        );
```

for both of them I get the first value logged once (before the filter/flatMap), the second value logged twice from the taps and once with "complete", and the third one once.

I thought the difference would be that emitting `EMPTY` would cause the observable to close entirely but subsequent values are still seen through the pipe.

I've done the same with a `Subject` and the only difference was that the `Subject`s didn't emit `Complete` which was to be expected.

Comment: `of` completes after emitting the supplied values, `EMPTY` completes without emitting any values. That doesn't necessarily mean the consumer has to complete too.

Comment: What test could I write to see the difference? The outputs for the tests I wrote are identical.

Comment: Because the behaviour's identical. Why do you think there *is* any difference?

Comment: That's specifically my question - if there is a functional difference between `filter` and `flatMap`ing into `EMPTY`.

Comment: I don't understand *why* that's your question, given that your experiment has already answered it (as: no) and demonstrated that `flatMap`ping `EMPTY` (or, for that matter, `of`) *doesn't* cause the outer observable to complete too. Also why were you looking to reimplement `filter` to begin with?

Comment: I thought my test might not cover functionality that would behave differently.

I found code that does `flatMap` into `EMPTY` and wanted to replace it with `filter`, but was unsure if that would preserve the functionality exactly.

Comment: There could be a difference if Observable returned from `flatMap` have different scheduler, but in your example visible behavior should be the same

Comment: @OlesSavluk can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a difference if Observable returned from `flatMap` have different scheduler, but in your example visible behavior should be the same. Usually this can happen if you rely on side effects, which is generally discouraged.

Here is example when `asyncScheduler` change behavior (values printed after creation in the second example):

```js
const { of, asyncScheduler, EMPTY, from } = rxjs; // = require("rxjs")
const { filter, flatMap } = rxjs.operators; // = require("rxjs/operators")

const items$ = from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

console.log("------------ SYNC");
const sync$ = items$.pipe(
  filter(v => v % 2 === 0)
);
sync$.subscribe(e => console.log(e));
console.log("after sync");


console.log("------------ ASYNC");
items$.pipe(
  flatMap(v => v % 2 === 0 ? of(v, asyncScheduler) : EMPTY)
).subscribe(e => console.log(e));
console.log("after async");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.5.2/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So can the difference only stem from `flatMap` altering the returned observable? If I return it exactly, are the two pipes identical?

Comment: They are not "identical", but should be safe to refactor this way in most cases